# Prove that $A\cap (B\setminus C)=(A \cap B)\setminus(A \cap C)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Problem: Prove that $A\cap (B\setminus C)=(A \cap B)\setminus(A \cap C)$.

I've tried it on my own:
\begin{align}
x&\in A\cap (B\setminus C) \\
&\Leftrightarrow (x\in A) \wedge (x\in B\setminus C) \\
&\Leftrightarrow (x\in A) \wedge (x\in B \wedge x\notin C) \\
&\Leftrightarrow (x\in A \wedge x\in B) \wedge (x\notin C) \\
&\Leftrightarrow x\in (A\cap B)\setminus C\\
&\Leftrightarrow \dots
\end{align}
What would the next step be? I've no idea how to get from $x\in (A\cap B)\setminus C$ to $x\in(A \cap B)\setminus(A \cap C)$.

If I'm trying to do the right side, we get
\begin{align}
x&\in(A \cap B)\setminus(A \cap C)\\
&\Leftrightarrow (x\in A \wedge x\in B)\wedge x\notin (A \cap C)\\
&\Leftrightarrow (x\in A \wedge x\in B)\wedge  (x\notin A \wedge x\notin C)\\
&\Leftrightarrow \dots
\end{align}
How do I make it simpler?

Comment: $(A \cap B)\setminus(A \cap C) = (A \cap B)\setminus C$

Comment: In other words, you're done.  Good job.

Comment: @AjmalW: The latter one is not correct: $x\notin (A \cap C)$ means $(x\notin A \vee x\notin C)$.

Comment: [Proving : $A \cap (B-C) = (A \cap B) - (A \cap C) $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9719/proving-a-cap-b-c-a-cap-b-a-cap-c); [Need help with set equivalence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526779/need-help-with-set-equivalence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replaced $x\notin A\cap C$ with $(x\notin A)\land(x\notin C)$, which is incorrect.

The correct one would be:

$$x\notin A\cap C \\
\Leftrightarrow \neg (x\in A\cap C)\\
\Leftrightarrow \neg (x\in A \land x\in C)\\
\Leftrightarrow (x\notin A)\lor (x\notin C) 
$$

Try, whether you can finish the problem using this.

Comment: So $((x\in A) \wedge (x\in B))\wedge  ((x\notin A) \vee  (x\notin C))\Leftrightarrow ((x\in A) \wedge (x\in B))\wedge  (x\notin C)$ because $x\notin A$ is false due to the existence of $x\in A$, according to @Martin Sleziak's first link?

Comment: Other way to say this is that $(p\land q)\land(\neg p \lor r) \Leftrightarrow (p\land q)\land r$ is a tautology for any statements p, q, r. In this case we use this tautology for $p\equiv x\in A$, $q\equiv x\in B$ and $r\equiv x\in C$.

Answer (score 2):

This is why I like characteristic functions, [see this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493071/show-that-a-cup-ba-cap-b-a-b/493859#493859)

With Characteristic functions we have

$$\chi_{(A \cap B)\setminus(A \cap C)}= \chi_{A \cap B}-\chi_{A \cap B}\chi_{A \cap C}
=\chi_A \chi_B -\chi_A \chi_B\chi_A \chi_C \\
=\chi_A \chi_B -\chi_A \chi_B\chi_C= \chi_A( \chi_B -\chi_{B} \chi_C)=\chi_A \chi_{B \setminus C}=\chi_{(A \cap (B \setminus C)} $$

Answer (score 0):

it's the same as multiplying a fractions,  A . B   then A . C  = (A Union B )\ (A union C)

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). For example you can write $A\cup B$ using `$A\cup B$` or $C\setminus D$ as `$C\setminus D$`.