# Show $A \cap (B-C) = (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$ using an alternative proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, alternative-proof

I am trying to prove that $$A \cap (B-C) = (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$$ holds for any sets $A,B,C$. This is equal to $$A \cap (B-C) = (A \cap B)\cap\color{red}{(A\cap C)'}.$$

I have seen a similar question: [Proving : $A \cap (B-C) = (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9719/proving-a-cap-b-c-a-cap-b-a-cap-c) but I am trying to use another approach, if it is correct.

We pick $$x\in A\cap(B-C)\to x\in A\wedge(x\in B\wedge x\in C')\underbrace{\to}_{\text{Identity}}(x\in A\wedge x\in B)\wedge x\in C'\wedge(x\in A\vee x\in A').$$ Then the first part is the same as $x\in A\cap B$. So we focus on: $x\in C'\wedge(x\in A\vee x\in A')$.

A friend of mine distributed so **I ask you if from $$(x\in C'\wedge x\in A)\vee(x\in C'\vee x\in A')\tag{1}$$ we can conclude $$\color{red}{x\in(A\cap C)'}.$$**

---

From $(1)$ we get that $x\in A-C\vee x\in(A\cap C)'$, but I can't proceed further.

I know the following laws:

- Addition: $p\to p\vee q$. **EDIT.** Since by this property we can finish quickly let me assume that we can't use Addition law.
- Simplification: $p\wedge q\to p$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
1. $ x \in C' \rightarrow x \in (A \cap C)' $ and
2. $ x \in A' \rightarrow x \in (A \cap C)' $

What you need follows from these two (try to see how).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't notice that if we use your (1) then we can finish quickly. So let me say that we are not able to use addition law. Can we proceed further without that law?

Comment: @manooooh $ x \in C' \rightarrow x \notin C \rightarrow x \notin  A \cap C \rightarrow x \in (A \cap C)' $ , isn't this acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

(A Inter B) - (A Inter C)

= (A Inter B) Inter (A Inter C)'

= (A Inter B) Inter ( A' Union C')

( by De Morgan)

= [(A Inter B ) Inter A'] Union [ ( A Inter B) Inter C']

( by distributivity)

= Empty Set Union [ A Inter ( B Inter C')]

( by associativity of intersection)

= A Inter ( B Inter C')

= A Inter ( B - C )

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please put LaTeX on it so I can understand it?

Comment: You may rewrite it substituting symbols for words. That may help you. Sorry, I'm not able to use LaTeX.

Comment: Nor can I use this barbarian MathJax language.